# Cheapest way to host a simple node server and website with very few daily views on Google Cloud Platform

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud

So I've been teaching myself some basic web development recently. I built a simple react based website that also has a nodejs server that handles some oauth2 stuff and a couple other API calls. Right now I'm hosting the services on the gcloud VMs. There's two instances: one for hosting the react server and another for the nodejs server. Unfortunately, running these two is costing me ~8$ a day. At that rate I'll be broke within the month. I'm trying to figure out how to reduce this cost to be more manageable. I believe the problem is that the instances are configured to be up and running constantly. There will only be a handful of website visitors a week--10 at most. Is there a way to get the instance to sleep when not in use? Is the problem with the `.yaml` configuration for the services? I would also be willing to switch to another service if necessary, but if possible I would like to keep it on gcloud since I already have the DNS and everything set up for it.

I've already tried searching Stack Overflow for other solutions. I found a couple examples of potential `.yaml`'s to use. It appears as if one of the solutions reduced the expenditures *slightly*. From 10$ a day to 8$ a day.

My initial `yaml`'s for both of the instances was

```
# [START runtime]
runtime: nodejs10
env: flex
# [END runtime]
```

After finding another suggestion, it has been switched to

```
# [START runtime]
runtime: nodejs
env: flex
manual_scaling:
  instances: 1
#resources:
#  cpu: .5
#  memory_gb: 0.18
#  disk_size_gb: 10
# [END runtime]
```

I also tried

```
runtime: nodejs8
instance_class: F1
automatic_scaling:
  max_instances: 1
```

But had problems with this configuration for some reason. It didn't seem to work, I couldn't connect to the website with that config, but maybe I just did something wrong.

Comment: Review the Google services "App Engine Standard", "Cloud Run", "Compute Engine - f1-micro instance size" and "Firebase". They will range from a few dimes ($0.10) to $6.00 per month. Each service has Quick Start guides for node.js. Google also has a pricing calculator. https://cloud.google.com/products/calculator/

Comment: The overall cheapest way to host a static web on GCP it's on [Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/hosting-static-website?hl=es-419). Now if you want to have a dynamic web I would suggest you deploy it on a Compute Engine f1 since its free to run a simple instance of this kind 24/7 for free